# How to play audio from isolated storage (except stream method)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, isolatedstorage

I find that in `SaveRingtoneTask` example from Microsoft used:

```
saveRingtoneChooser.Source = new Uri(@"isostore:/" + ringtonePath);
```

I use Uri like this to play audio by `MediaPlayer` but there are no exceptions or sounds.

Comment: show your actual code. Don't just describe it or show code that is like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "isostore:/" prefix only seems to be supported in certain narrow scenarios - like setting the live tile image or perhaps as in your example - to save a ringtone. There is an article on doing what you ask for with BackgroundAudioPlayer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

If you just need to play back the files inside your application - you can use MediaElement.SetSource() to point to a stream of the file opened from isolated storage.